# How to add base repositories in Ubuntu docker image?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apt

My application depends on this package:

```bash
sudo apt-cache policy lynx
```

```bash
lynx:
  Installed: 2.9.0dev.12-1
  Candidate: 2.9.0dev.12-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.9.0dev.12-1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But, I'm unable to install it in the ubuntu docker image, with:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y lynx
```

If I connect to the running docker container, I can't issue the command, and I can't find a command in order to add the right ppa which contains the lynx (http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu).

`add-ppa-repository` command is not available in the docker image.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue, neither with ubuntu:22.04 (which installs lynx 2.9.0dev.10-1) nor ubuntu:23.04 (which installs lynx 2.9.0dev.12-1)

Comment: See: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/ba4e0320c6dc3b33701868ffeb8c133d as a working minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I found my mistake. I was using `FROM golang` afterwards, which shadowed the previous section, in which I installed `lynx`. I just used `FROM golang:bookworm` and everything worked out.

Comment: If you have a Go application, can you use the `net/http` package as an HTTP client, instead of calling out to a separate command-line HTTP client?

Comment: I don't want to couple my front-end and back-end. Else, I could, indeed serve the index with `fasthttp` (which is what I'm using).